# How to Determine If a Collection Is Empty

Tags: java, exception, collections

I have a 3 dimensional ArrayList and I want to determine if it is empty or not. There is an exception called **EmptyCollectionException** which is not part of java standard library and hence I'm not allowed to use it.

Is there a way to accomplish that using a native java exception or function?

The 3D List is constructed as follow:

```
public void makeRandomCardListForLearning (Course courseToBeMadeRandom) {

    List<List<List<Card>>> course = new ArrayList<List<List<Card>>>(); 

    for(Chapter chptr: courseToBeMadeRandom.getChapterList()) {
        List<List<Card>> chapter = new ArrayList<List<Card>>();
        course.add(chapter);

        for(Deck dck: chptr.getDeckList()) {
            List<Card> deck = new LinkedList<Card>();
            chapter.add(deck);

            for(Card crd: dck.getCardList()) {
                if(dck.isTheCardDueToday(crd.getLastDate())) {
                    deck.add(crd);
                }
            }
            Collections.shuffle(deck);
        }
    }
}
```

As I go through course, chapter and deck I create a List for each one. There is only one course, many chapters, many decks and of course many cards which are saved under deck doublyLinkedList if they pass the pre-condition. If no card passes the condition, I have a 3D list which exists but has no cards. And I want to determine that If no card exists in the list, then the user receives an error message.

In fact I only need the cards. But I also need to know in which deck each card resides at the moment. If I just make a list and go through all chapters and decks and put cards in that list based on the condition then I have no clue in which chapter and deck each card resides. That can be solved by maybe adding two attributes to the card class. But that was a mistake as we designed the system and adding them now costs a lot of change in other parts of the program. Each index in course List represents the chapter number and each index in chapter list represents the deck number. I solved the problem that way.

Comment: can u show part of your code?

Comment: is `arrayList.isEmpty()` not sufficient?

Comment: how about `isEmpty()` method?

Comment: Why have you decided to use 3 nested Lists?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis My answer to your question was longer than the allowed limit ;) so I updated the question. Read please the last paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(List<List<List<Card>>> list3d) {
    return list3d.stream().flatMap(llc -> llc.stream()).flatMap(lc -> lc.stream()).count() == 0;
}
```

It takes into account that the outer lists may contain empty inner lists. It deems the entire 3D list empty if there are no cards in it.

Comment: Compact, precise, to the point. Exactly what I wanted! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
         List<List<List<Card>>> course = new ArrayList<List<List<Card>>>(); 
                  // some possible codes
         boolean check = course.isEmpty()
                    // other possible codes
                if (check) {
           // do something
                            }
```

or any arraylist you want to check or any way you want to reach your goal

Comment: I want to check it at the end not at the beginning. In fact I want to know if a card exists in one of the lists or is the list only made of course, chapters, decks and no cards under any decks. Because eventually I need to work with cards.

Comment: i have placed it in a if to show its a boolean value.and its only a example of how it works.you can write your code and use it however you want.let me edit it